# Build errors installing knowrob

Tags: ros, cram, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So I follow instructions reported here to install knowrob http://cram-project.org/installation

After I run catkin_make I get the following error

Gradling tasks for json_prolog
Gradling tasks for knowrob_srdl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/rohan/Peretec_work/workspace/ros_kb/src/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'json_prolog'.

I have installed rosjava and I am using ros-indigo on ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210412/build-errors-installing-knowrob/) by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, Gradle is very fragile and constantly complains about weird stuff. Usually it complains after rosjava updates, so if you recently updated your Indigo packages that might have been the cause. I usually remove the `~/.gradle` directory (the one in your home) and sometimes also the `build` and `devel` in my workspace and recompile everything and that helps. Otherwise, from the information you provided it's hard to say anything else, you'd need to tell us how exactly you're installing KnowRob, your workspace setup etc... Maybe @moritz has a better idea.

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0